# Random ordered sample without replacement in R

Tags: r, random

The function RandomKSubsets from https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/eastwest.pdf
draws an ordered subset without replacement from a set of numbers.

`

```
RandomKSubsets:=proc(n,k)
local rno,east,west ;
if n<0 or k<0 or k>n then RETURN()
    elif n=0 and k=0 then RETURN([])
    else
rno:=10^(-12)*rand();
if rno<k/n then
    east:=RandomKSubsets(n-1,k-1);
    RETURN([op(east),n])
        else
    west:=RandomKSubsets(n-1,k);
    RETURN(west)
fi;fi;
end:
```

`

Is there a package in R that does the same thing? Or can somebody help with translating it into R?

Comment: Check out the `sample` function. It allows you to sample from a vector of numbers with or without replacement

Comment: I want to sample uniformly from the set of all ordered integers. Sample function does not do that.

Comment: `sample` samples based on the frequency of the values. If you want to change that, then use the `probs` argument to specify 1/n or whatever

Comment: It's too slow to calculate all the probabilities for large n and k.

Comment: slow vs fast is a different question. You could make it faster and in R by moving the above algorithm into Cpp via Rcpp and thats probably as fast as it will get

Comment: what is the "op" object? It isn't defined in your function?. Never mind, that is a maple function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sample` is indeed slow for large `n`. One call takes on average ~15 s on my computer for the following parameters:

```
set.seed(123)

n_int <- 1.e7
n_s <- 1000

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(sample.int(n_int, n_s, prob = rep(1/n_int, n_int)),
                               times = 5L,
                               unit = 's')
```

For more computationally efficient sampling, one can use the `wrswoR` package ([CRAN](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/wrswoR/index.html)). It implements several algorithms for weighted sampling without replacement. For example, `sample_int_expj` achieves the same task in ~0.07 s on average.

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(wrswoR::sample_int_expj(n_int, n_s, prob = rep(1/n_int, n_int)),
                               times = 5L,
                               unit = 's')
```